# Showing a array defined in a class Angular

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

I am trying to show a list of content using an array in angular.
The app, however, does not seem to return any data.
The load still works, because other apps do load in.

The service has been added to the app.module.ts.
The imports do not give any errors indicating a wrong connection.

Class:

```
export class Bike
{
    id: number;
    model: string;
    manufacturer: string;
}
```

app-component.html:

```
<h1>   {{title}} </h1>
<hr />

<app-bike></app-bike>
```

bikes.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Bike } from '../bike';


@Injectable()
export class BikesService
{
getBikes(): Bike[]
{

    //return
    return [
        { id: 1, model: 'CBR250R', manufacturer: 'Honda' },
        { id: 2, model: 'CBR150R', manufacturer: 'Honda' },
        { id: 3, model: 'Ninja250R', manufacturer: 'Kawasaki' },
        { id: 4, model: 'CBR1000R', manufacturer: 'Honda' },
        { id: 5, model: 'Ninja1000RR', manufacturer: 'Kawasaki' }
    ];
}

}
```

bikes.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BikesService } from '../services/bikes.service';


@Component({
selector: 'app-bike',
templateUrl: './bike.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./bike.component.css']
})
export class BikeComponent implements OnInit
{
//properties
title: string = "Bikes";
bikes:any[]

//constructor
constructor(bikesService: BikesService)
{
    //init prop
    this.bikes = bikesService.getBikes();
}


//lifeCycle
ngOnInit()
{
}

}
```

bike.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let bike of bikes">{{bike}}</div>
```

I know that i would need something similar to bike.model for the html, but i do not get any output, not even object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add service as provider to the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bike',
  templateUrl: './bike.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bike.component.css'],
  providers: [BikesService]
})
```

Comment: @user3110254 no problem :D